# Атака на шифр Виженера

Tags: python, криптография, шифрование

Задача собственно расшифровать сообщение зашифрованное шифром Виженера.
Сообщение соответственно зашифровал я сам и ключ мне известен. Сейчас пытаюсь решить задачу в частном случае.

1.Хотел бы увидеть ваше мнение по нахождению индекса совпадений, так как не уверен в его правильности.

2.Ошибку в частотном анализе, почему-то не получается правильная разница между символами.

```
group1 = []
group2 = []
ord_a = ord('a')
mes = 'zcdlyrswdlofowd'
mas = list(mes)
le = len(mas)
count_i = 0
# индекс совпадений
for i in range(0, len(mas), 2):
    count = mas.count(mas[i]) - 1
    count_i += count
index = (count_i * (count_i - 1)) / (le * (le - 1))
# разбиваем текст по длине ключа, со сдвигом
for i in range(0, len(mas), 2):
    group1.append(mas[i])
for i in range(1, len(mas), 2):
    group2.append(mas[i])
# сдвигаем группы на нужное количество символов влево
# группа1 = самая частая буква d. разница между e и d = 1, правильный ответ 10
# группа2 = самая частая буква w или l. соответствующая разница 19 или 7, правильный ответ 4.
for i in range(len(group1)):
    tmp = ord(group1[i]) - ord_a
    tmp1 = 10
    tmp2 = ((tmp - tmp1) % 26)
    print(chr(tmp2 + ord_a), end = '')
print(' ')   
for i in range(len(group2)):
    tm = ord(group2[i]) - ord_a
    tm1 = 4
    tm2 = ((tm - tm1) % 26)
    print(chr(tm2 + ord_a), end = '')

print('\n', group1, group2)
```